# How to set ansible var with value from the environment variable

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

How do I pull the env var and write it to a file on the target host?

```yaml
- name: get Super Secret
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    ansible_super_secret: "{{ lookup('env', 'SUPER_SECRET') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost

- copy: 
    content: "{{ ansible_super_secret }}" 
    dest: "{{ config_file_path }}"
```

Is there a better way to make the env var on the ansible host available on the target machine?

Comment: HI, Vladimir, I as looking to write the secret  I got from the file env var to a file in that directory. I just wanted to grab the secret value in ansible so that it can be written to every host  in the play book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"How do I pull the env var and write it to a file on the target host?"***

A: Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

The below playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: /root/.ansible_super_secret
        content: "{{ lookup('env', 'SUPER_SECRET') }}"
        owner: root
        mode: '0600'
```

creates files on the remote hosts

```yaml
shell> SUPER_SECRET='super secret' ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [copy] ***********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Take a look at the files

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 sudo cat /root/.ansible_super_secret
super secret
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 sudo cat /root/.ansible_super_secret
super secret
```

---

Q: ***"Is there a better way to make the env var on the ansible host available on the target machine?"***

A: The [*lookup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) plugins run always on the controller. If you [*run_once*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once) the task *set_fact* all hosts in the playbook will get the variable. The below playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        ansible_super_secret: "{{ lookup('env', 'SUPER_SECRET') }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: ansible_super_secret
```

gives

```yaml
shell> SUPER_SECRET='super secret' ansible-playbook pb2.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_super_secret: super secret
ok: [test_13] => 
  ansible_super_secret: super secret

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```